# PHP switch statement variable scope

Tags: php, switch-statement, scope

In PHP, how is variable scope handled in switch statements?

For instance, take this hypothetical example:

```
$someVariable = 0;

switch($something) {

    case 1:
        $someVariable = 1;
        break;

    case 2:
        $someVariable = 2;
        break;
}

echo $someVariable;
```

Would this print 0 or 1/2?

Comment: Why don’t you just try it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variable will be the same in your whole portion of code : there is not variable scope "per block" in PHP.

So, if `$something` is `1` or `2`, so you enter in one of the `case` of the `switch`, your code would output 1 or 2.

On the other hand, if `$something` is not `1` nor `2` *(for instance, if it's considered as `0`, which is the case with the code you posted, as it's not initialized to anything)*, you will not enter in any of the `case` block ; and the code will output `0`.

Comment: Even if PHP had lexical scope, `$someVariable` would still be accessible in the `switch` block.

Answer (score 6):

PHP does only have a [global and function/method scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). So `$someVariable` inside the `switch` block refers to the same variable as outside.

But since `$something` is not defined (at least not in the code you provided), accessing it raises a *Undefined variable* notice, none of the cases match (undefined variables equal `null`), `$someVariable` will stay unchanged and `0` will be printed out.

Answer (score 1):

It will print 1 or 2. Variables in PHP have the scope of the whole function.

Answer (score 1):

It will print 1 or 2 if you change the value of `$someVariable` in the switch statement, and 0 if you don't.

Answer (score -1):

To give you a universally-correct answer, we would need to know the value of $something.

If we took your code at face value, $something would be undefined....and since there is no "default" case, $someVariable would just stay 0.

If $something was 1, $someVariable would be 1.

If $something was 2, $someVariable would be 2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).