# How do I retrieve the values I assign to variables in one switch case block in another switch case block in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, scope, switch-statement

In PHP is there a way to access the value that I assign to a variable in one case block of a switch statement in another case block in that same switch statement? For instance, I want to access the value I assigned to $task_to_modify in the 'Modify Task' case block in the 'Save Changes' case block below.  Here's my code.  Any advice would help as I'm new to PHP.  Thanks.

```
$task_to_modify
switch( $_POST['action'] ) {
case 'Add Task':
    $new_task = $_POST['newtask'];
    if (empty($new_task)) {
        $errors[] = 'The new task cannot be empty.';
    } else {
        //$task_list[] = $new_task; //original code
        array_push($task_list, $new_task);
    }
    break;
case 'Delete Task':
    $task_index = $_POST['taskid'];
    unset($task_list[$task_index]);
    $task_list = array_values($task_list);
    break;
case 'Modify Task':
    global $key;
    $key = $_POST['taskid']; //taskid is index of selected task from tasks selection list
    global $task_to_modify;
    $task_to_modify = $task_list[$key];
    set_task_to_modify($task_to_modify);
    echo "modify task case reached. task_to_modify is " . $task_to_modify;
    break;
case 'Save Changes':
    global $task_to_modify;
    if(in_array($new_task, $task_list)) { //if old value is in the list
        $index = array_search($new_task, $task_list); //return index # of old value
        $task_list[$index] = $task_to_modify; //replaces old value with newly entered value
        unset($task_to_modify); //deletes var so original form will show
    }
    break;
case 'Cancel Changes': //works correctly
    echo 'no changes saved';
    unset($task_to_modify);
    break;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has no scope for each block. So the variable is available in the 'modify task' block and in the 'save changes' block, since they share the same scope. You might also take a look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306263/php-switch-statement-variable-scope) to understand it a little bit better.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and link, but it still isn't working for me.  I've declared my $task_to_modify variable and initialized it to '' outside the switch statement, and I've assigned a value to it in my Modify Task case block, but I'm still unable to access that value in my Save Changes case block.  My code follows the same format as the code in the link you provided, but for some reason it still doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect you're getting a wrong idea of how those variable works. After the script is launched and terminated all those variables get erased, so if you refresh no $task_to_modify will be defined. If you are searching for persistent variables you should take a look at sessions.

Comment: I never thought about the script executing and terminating.  I found a solution.  It's a little sloppy, but at least it works.  Thanks.